# Make a radio button checked depending on the value in database

Tags: c#, oledb

Through this code I am retreiving the values from database in edit form:

```
OleDbCommand Comm1 = new OleDbCommand("select image1,image2,image3,image4,measurement,property_purpose,bedrooms,bathrooms,furnishing,property_price,property_price_per_mu,existing_customer from  tb_property where property_id = ?", con);
Comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("property_id", txt_prop_id.Text);
OleDbDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();
if (DR1.Read())
       {
          txt_image1.Text = DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
          txt_image2.Text = DR1.GetValue(1).ToString();
          txt_image3.Text = DR1.GetValue(2).ToString();
          txt_image4.Text = DR1.GetValue(3).ToString();
          combo_measure.Text = DR1.GetValue(4).ToString();
          combo_purpose.Text = DR1.GetValue(5).ToString();

          combo_bedrooms.Text = DR1.GetValue(6).ToString();
          combo_bathrooms.Text = DR1.GetValue(7).ToString();
          combo_furnishing.Text = DR1.GetValue(8).ToString();
          txt_price.Text = DR1.GetValue(9).ToString();
          txt_price_per_mu.Text = DR1.GetValue(10).ToString();
          var val = DR1.GetValue(11).ToString();
          if (val == "Yes")
          {
              radioButton1.Checked;
          }
          if (val == "No")
          {
              radioButton2.Checked;
          }
       }
```

Now I am having trouble with the `radiobuttons` if the `val` is `Yes` in the database then `radiobutton1` should be checked.

If `No` is in database then `radiobutton2` should be selected. But the syntax is an showing error, can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4):

Syntax for setting checked propery of radiobutton is

```
radioButton1.Checked = true;
```

So ur code would look like

```
          if (val == "Yes")
          {
              radioButton1.Checked=true;
              radioButton2.Checked=false;
          }
          else if (val == "No")
          {
              radioButton2.Checked=true;
              radioButton1.Checked=false;
          }
```

Comment: Makes no sense for two if statements use `else if`

Answer (score 1):

Just update `Checked` property of the radiobuttons:

```
  radioButton1.Checked = (val == "Yes);
  radioButton2.Checked = !radioButton1.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nitin Varpe's answer is great but there is one more thing I would improve on your code and that is indexing columns by it's

put this code in class:

```
public static class DataExtensions
    {
    public static string GetSafeString(this OleDbDataReader reader, string colName)
    {

        if (reader[colName] != DBNull.Value)
            return reader[colName].ToString();
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

So when you call for value it will look like this:

```
con.Open();
OleDbDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();

if (DR1.Read())
{

   textBox1.Text = (DataExtensions.GetSafeString(DR1, "COLUMN"));
   var val = (DataExtensions.GetSafeString(DR1, "COLUMN"));

   if (val == "Yes")
   {
       radioButton1.Checked;
   }
   if (val == "No")
   {
       radioButton2.Checked;
   }
}

con.Close();
```

Indexing columns might lead messing up whole code when changing the table structure.
Hope it helped a little.